# Firebase Auth rule read if exists in subcollection not working

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am attempting to read a clan only if the users uid is a document in the subcollection members but i cant seem to get it to work just more permission errors.

```
match /clans/{clanName} {
    allow create;
    allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/clans/{clanName}/members/$(request.auth.uid))
            match /members/{uid} {
            allow create,write,delete: if uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
}
```

The code that is calling this is using a reference stored in another document

```
this.getProfile
    .data()
    .clan.get());
```

which equates to

```
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("clans")
    .doc(clanName)
    .get()
```

[image]

[image]

```
leaveClan() {
  console.log(this.getUser.displayName + " leaving " + this.getProfile);
  console.log(this.getProfile.data().clan.get().collection("members")
    .doc(this.getUser.uid));
  this.getProfile
    .clan
    .get()
    .collection("members")
    .doc(this.getUser.uid)
    .delete()
    .then(() => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("profiles")
        .doc(this.getUser.uid)
        .update({
          clan: null
        });
    });
},
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to say why these rules aren't working for you without seeing: 1) the minimal code that reproduces the error, 2) the data that the code or rules access. Please edit your question to include this information. I always recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance there helps you maximize the chances that someone can help you.

Comment: added the calling code.

Comment: Thanks. That leaves #2: the data that the code and rules access. Please add a screenshot of a document that the rules are reading. 3) be sure to also show the value of `clanName` as we have no way of knowing that otherwise. I always recommend simply `console.log(clanName)` right before this query, and including both the updated code and its output in the question.

Comment: Wouldn't the promise from the reference already have the document?

I was hoping since the reference has the clan name in it then it would know.

I dont keep the clanname i keep the reference to the clan document. You can see that under profiles => uid => clan: /clans/auth check which references clans => auth check. I want the user only to be able to read the clan document if they are present in the member subcollection via uid.

Comment: Your code is doing `.doc(clanName)`. Logging the value as I requested ensures it has the value that you expect, and that we can help you verify that. You'll also want to log the UID in the same way, so that we can all check that it matches what you have in the datbase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your embedding `{clanName}` in the `get()` call is incorrect. Variables are all in `$(variablename)` format, similar to how you already have `$(database)` and `$(request.auth.uid)`.

So something like:

```
if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/clans/$(clanName)/members/$(request.auth.uid))
```

Also see:

- The Firebase documentation on [accessing other documents in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).